TypeError: x.pubkey.equals is not a function
I'm only using client-side pure Javascript here, I pkged a few required libs using browserify (bs58, buffer). All want to figure out how to connect with Phantom wallet and then sign a transaction, but I always get this error at my last line when I call sendAndConfirmTransaction():
TypeError: x.pubkey.equals is not a function
at legacy.ts:486:23
at Array.findIndex (<anonymous>)
at Transaction.compileMessage (legacy.ts:485:39)
at Transaction._compile (legacy.ts:577:26)
at Transaction.sign (legacy.ts:685:26)
at Connection.sendTransaction (connection.ts:5965:21)
at async Object.sendAndConfirmTransaction (send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:36:9)
at async index.html:48:13

Here's my full code:
const Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;

    (async () => {
        const getProvider = () => {
            if ('phantom' in window) {
                const provider = window.phantom?.solana;

                if (provider?.isPhantom) {
                    return provider;
                }
            }

            window.open('https://phantom.app/', '_blank');
        };

        const provider = getProvider();
        try {
            const wallet = await provider.connect();
            console.log(wallet.publicKey.toString());
            const network = "https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=";
            const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(network);
            const transferAmount = 0.01;

        const transferInstruction = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
            toPubkey: "8jwDvVpTUyfpLuQRVimBnhafDJqR8458U9rp1SXASFB3",
            lamports: transferAmount * 100,
        });

        const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(transferInstruction);

        let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;
        transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
        transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

        await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [wallet]);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })();


The transfer instruction expects public key arguments for the values.
const from pubkey = wallet.publicKey;
const toPubkey = new PublicKey("8jwDvVpTUyfpLuQRVimBnhafDJqR8458U9rp1SXASFB3");

const transferInstruction = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey,
            toPubkey,
            lamports: transferAmount * 100,
        });

